# how to do? User type some numbers and then another function return result of addition of these numbers? (C/C++)

Tags: c++, c, calculator

how to do? User type some numbers and then another function return result of addition of these numbers? (C/C++)

for example, user type in 3 4 7 and then he see printed on screen 14
another one, user type 5 6 and gets 11

I'm a beginner in programming C, so I ask you to help me, please

Comment: Is this Homework? Please mark it if this is.

Comment: It's better to ask a more specific question, rather than asking others to write the entire program for you.  Are you having trouble with IO? math? functions?  Also, with regard to C vs. C++, please pick one.

Comment: Is this C or C++?  They aren't the same language, you know.

Answer (score 4):

At a high level:

- take the input string
- split it by white space
- parse each part to an integer
- add the integers
- return the result

This is as simple as it can get without actually posting code, which I won't do as I suspect this is a homework assignment.

Answer (score 2):

because   the number of arguments  is not specified i think you need  va_list  but  as you said you are new in c++ so  you can write it  like this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    int sum=0;
    int t;
    while ((cin>>t)!=EOF)//in windows EOF is  ctrl+z
    {
        sum+=t;
    }

    cout<<sum<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't test for EOF. There are other error conditions. Use `while (cin >> t)` Thus the loop will work while there is valid input and stop when somthing becomes invalid. In your version it will stop working when a non integer is types but the loop will not end.